# Fractal of an image used as a feature vector

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fractals

I am working on an image processing/classification project on Matlab and I'm looking to create a feature vector based on **fractal dimensions**.

[image]

Take a look at these 2 sample images for example.

From what I understand, the object in `image 1` has a much higher fractal value than the object in `image 2`.

Right now, I have used `k-means` to segment the dark green colored objects from the 2 images. How can I approach coding up a function to calculate a fractal value for the segment.

Thanks and please do correct me if my understanding on fractals is inaccurate.

Comment: have a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13063-boxcount/content/boxcount/html/demo.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use shape context descriptor to describe the shape. Since you can easily segment the dark green region. Try to understand the effect of being fractal or not. 
Train SVM and check if the shape context can capture this property